# Issue with Ansible uri JSON parsing

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

In Ansible, using the `uri` module to retrieve some JSON, then output one of the fields using `debug`.

```
  - name: debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.json.results[0].series[0].values }}"
```

The JSON data contains a key called `values` and this seems to match the Python keyword `values()`. So instead of returning the value for that key it's returning an object.

```
ok: [XXX] => {
    "msg": "<built-in method values of dict object at 0x7fd131418280>"
}
```

Any idea how I can protect the call from being interpreted in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can try is to access it via the square brackets notation rather:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ result.json.results[0].series[0]['values'] }}"
```

If this still doesn't work, the [`.get(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method of Python's dictionaries should comes in handy:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ result.json.results[0].series[0].get('values') }}"
```

---

So indeed with:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ result.json.results[0].series[0].values }}"
      vars:
          result:
            json:
              results:
                - series:
                    - values: foo
```

We get:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "<built-in method values of dict object at 0x7fb3111e9cc0>"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But with:

- either

  ```yaml
  - hosts: all
    gather_facts: no

    tasks:
      - debug: 
          msg: "{{ result.json.results[0].series[0]['values'] }}"
        vars:
            result:
              json:
                results:
                  - series:
                      - values: foo
  ```
- or

  ```yaml
  - hosts: all
    gather_facts: no

    tasks:
      - debug: 
          msg: "{{ result.json.results[0].series[0].get('values') }}"
        vars:
            result:
              json:
                results:
                  - series:
                      - values: foo
  ```

You do get:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "foo"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: This is more of a Jinja question than an Ansible question; the relevant documentation is [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#variables), which suggests that the first solution (using `[]`) will work.

Comment: @larsks I concur after a test, both works. I was wondering because I also saw one question about a dictionary with an `items` key that was totally messing with an internal behaviour of Ansible. Thanks for pointing to the relevant documentation.

Comment: Yeah, the first the proposal works. I should have thought of that. Thanks.